# In MRI Ruby 2.0+ - are modules loaded once into memory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, memory

If you have a module in Ruby you are expecting that particular object (since everything is an object in Ruby) to not have any instances. How is the memory consumption for that allocated in the interpreter then? I know for Ruby symbols for example the interpreter will load one instance of that constant and reuse that memory every single time it's referenced outside of that. Does it do something similar for Module objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the answer you're looking for is: a module/class name is a kind of constant in Ruby and it works similarly to symbols in the sense that there is only one module "instance" for a given name. The difference is that modules (and classes) can be reopened and modified repeatedly, e.g. (on my machine and MRI/YARV 2.2.3):

```
module Foo
  def a; end
end

p Foo.object_id # < 47210744068460
p Foo.instance_methods(false) # < [:a]

module Foo
  def b; end
end

p Foo.object_id # < 47210744068460
p Foo.instance_methods(false) # < [:a, :b]
```

So it's the same object, but it changes state over time. You could in theory keep `load`'ing the same file containing a definition of a module over and over again and each time Ruby would evaluate it and overwrite the attributes of the previous definition. (That's why you should use `require` instead; it won't re-load a file if it's already been loaded.) It won't create new modules and consume additional memory.

Answer (score 0):

The Ruby Language Specification does not say anything about how memory is allocated. Every implementor is free to choose memory allocation strategies, memory management strategies, object representations, memory optimizations, etc. as they wish. As long as they behave the same, internally, they can do whatever they want.

Comment: That makes sense and keeps it coherent I guess. The question really does look for an answer to a particular implementation though. Another question (which is the core problem I was having in my mind I guess) though that your answer leads me to is - does the Ruby Language Specification state how the Modules should behave (ie. similar to how the symbols object behavior is)? I know for MRI Ruby 2.0+ at least when you check object id for symbols two equivalent symbols will give the same object id but strings would differ.